# cmake - cpack component install deb is empty

Tags: cmake, cpack

I want to get deb packages of specific components. When I'm using specific toolchain file `IMX6` or `IMX8` variables are set. Output when using `IMX6`:

```
Run CPack packaging tool...
CPack: Create package using DEB
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: main_project
CPack: - Install project: main_project []
CPack: -   Install component: PRIMARY_DISPLAY
CPack: -   Install component: SECONDARY_DISPLAY
CPack: Create package
-- CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS not set, the package will have no dependencies.
-- CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS not set, the package will have no dependencies.
CPack: - package: /home/anzipex/Downloads/add_target_package_secondary_47154/debs_47154/unca_23/cmake-build-release-imx6/unca-1.0.1-Linux-PRIMARY_DISPLAY.deb generated.
CPack: - package: /home/anzipex/Downloads/add_target_package_secondary_47154/debs_47154/unca_23/cmake-build-release-imx6/unca-1.0.1-Linux-SECONDARY_DISPLAY.deb generated.
```

The problem is that created deb packages are empty inside. In directory `_CPack_Packages` deb packages have `data.tar.gz` and contains only empty `usr` directory. However if i set this variable:
`set(CPACK_MONOLITHIC_INSTALL 1)` main deb package has all data. What's wrong with that?

My main `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "Company")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)

if(NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL DESKTOP)
    set(CPACK_DEBIAN_DESKTOP_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "amd64")
    add_subdirectory(desktop)
elseif(IMX6)
    set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL PRIMARY_DISPLAY SECONDARY_DISPLAY)
    set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PRIMARY_DISPLAY_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "armhf")
    set(CPACK_DEBIAN_SECONDARY_DISPLAY_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "armhf")
    add_subdirectory(primary_display)
    add_subdirectory(secondary_display)
elseif(IMX8)
    set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL PRIMARY_DISPLAY SECONDARY_DISPLAY)
    set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PRIMARY_DISPLAY_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "arm64")
    set(CPACK_DEBIAN_SECONDARY_DISPLAY_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "arm64")
    add_subdirectory(primary_display)
    add_subdirectory(secondary_display)
endif()

include(CPack)
```

Example of `secondary_display/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/apps/secondary_display/resources DESTINATION /opt/unca COMPONENT secondary_display)

install(TARGETS secondary_display DESTINATION /opt/unca COMPONENT secondary_display)
install(TARGETS ahrs DESTINATION /opt/unca COMPONENT secondary_display)
install(TARGETS sns DESTINATION /opt/unca COMPONENT secondary_display)

install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION /var/opt/unca COMPONENT secondary_display
    DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS
    OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE
    GROUP_WRITE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE
    WORLD_WRITE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/configs/net.xml DESTINATION /var/opt/unca COMPONENT secondary_display)

install(FILES services/unca-secondary-display.service DESTINATION /etc/systemd/system/ COMPONENT secondary_display)
install(FILES services/unca-ahrs.service DESTINATION /etc/systemd/system/ COMPONENT secondary_display)
install(FILES services/unca-sns.service DESTINATION /etc/systemd/system/ COMPONENT secondary_display)

set(CPACK_DEBIAN_SECONDARY_DISPLAY_PACKAGE_NAME "unca-secondary-display")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_SECONDARY_DISPLAY_FILE_NAME "unca-secondary-display-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CPACK_DEBIAN_DESKTOP_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE}.deb")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_SECONDARY_DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION "UNCA SECONDARY DISPLAY")

string(CONCAT CPACK_DEBIAN_SECONDARY_DISPLAY_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/prerm;"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/preinst;"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/postinst"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines with `CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL` should be deleted from if in main `CMakeLists.txt`